# Setting SharePoint Workflow approver from code

Tags: forms, sharepoint, workflow

I am converting our Word HR forms for use on our intranet. I am creating them using InfoPath 2010 and Publishing to SharePoint forms library. I have prepopulated some fields such as name, telephone, manager etc by querying Active Directory. I need to setup an approval workflow and the first approver will always be the users manager. The manager field already has the manager populated but I don't know how to dynamically add it to the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a *Person/Group Picker* within InfoPath, you will need to promote the *AccountId* field to make it accessible to SharePoint workflows. This can be done when you publish your InfoPath form.

You can then assign the value of *AccountId* to first approver in your workflow.

Comment: I'm not using a person/group picker but the Line Manager TextBox is populated with the users Line Manager by Active Directory. It is the Line Manager that needs to be the first approver so I need to get that value from TextBox and somehow add it to be the first approver in Workflow. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Are you able to obtain the manager's login information from Active Directory: DOMAIN\USER ? If so you can assign this to a field in InfoPath and promote it.

Comment: I have the Managers name from an AD query so I should be able to do another AD query to get his login details. I'm not sure what you mean about promoting it in InfoPath though. Thanks for your help.